# Determining the length of the bases of a trapezoid knowing height and area as a function of smallest base length

Tags: geometry

For a trapezoid following data is given:

$h=a\sqrt{6}$

large base size ($a$) equals 3 time small base size ($b$),

$A=a^2\sqrt{3}$

The question is to calculate the base lengths.
Looks easy , but after filling in the equations i still could not get here.
Hope somebody can help.

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: That is geometry not abstract algebra

Comment: Puzzling! The description is that of a non-existent trapezoid. It may be worth checking whether the original question is the same as the one typed above.

Answer (score 1):

You already know that smaller base is $\frac{a}{3}$, since this is a third of the larger base's length. Now set up an equation using the area of a trapezoid.

$\frac{\frac{4a}{3}a\sqrt{6}}{2}=a^2\sqrt{3}$

Note that the $a^2$ will cancel out.

$\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{6}=\sqrt{3}$

This is a false statement, so such a trapezoid does not exist.

Comment: Hi Jed,

Thanks, this is correct. 

Marc

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $A=\frac{a+b}2\cdot h=2bh$.